# How to send form but with state value instead

Tags: next.js

I have a form tag like this

```
let [name,setName] = useState()

const check_typing = (e) => {
setName = e.target.value
}

<form method="POST" action={"http://localhost:3000/api/hello"}> 

<label>name</label>
<select>some value</select>  //this value from form  got eror in schema but state value are ok

<input onChange={check_typing}></input>
</form>
```

Can I change the form POST value to the value of state instead

Comment: i try to use button and change directly but there's some bug that the form require email but button keep sending data anyway

Answer (score 0):

The standard practice for declaring states in React is with const over let. Like the following:

`const [name,setName] = useState()`

Doing the above will have the added benefit of letting you know that you are using setName incorrectly.

Your check_typing function should look more like this:

```
const check_typing = (e) => {
  setName(e.target.value);
}
```

A google search of "How to create forms with nextjs" would have served you well.
One of the top hits: [forms with Next.js example](https://formeezy.com/examples/next-js-example)